# AutoHotKey. Website login notification

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to be notified when certain members login to a website. The site's list of logged-in members usually extends to three or four HTML pages, with each URL identical except for the page number at the end. I have a text file listing the few members for whom I'd like notifications. The script below successfully notifies me if any of the members in my list logs in. It downloads the first page, searches for each member on that page, notifies if found, then repeats the process with each remaining page before sleeping for five minutes and starting over.

There are dozens of ways that I'd like to improve this, but for starters I'd like to resolve a repeat notification issue. I'm notified every five minutes about the same member(s) for as long as they're logged in. Once I OK the MsgBox for a particular member, I'd like the script to keep searching for members withOUT re-notifying me of any previously acknowledged logins. I'm wondering if I should re-think this whole thing, get rid of MsgBox completely, and have an always-open window with a member/status list, and a SoundBeep only when there's a status change. Can AutoHotKey be used to implement that? I've only recently found AHK, and I have no programming or scripting experience, so it's taken me an embarrassingly long time to come up with what I have so far. Thanks for any assistance and suggestions.

```
Loop
{
    n := 1
    While n < 5
    {
        UrlDownloadToFile, website/LoggedIn&page=%n%, Source_%n%.txt
        FileRead, PageVar_%n%, Source_%n%.txt
        Loop, read, MemberList.txt
        {
            Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, `n
            {
                MemberVar = %A_LoopField%
                IfInString, PageVar_%n%, %MemberVar%
                {
                    SoundBeep
                    MsgBox, 4096, Logged In, %MemberVar% is logged in
                }
            }   
        }
        n := n + 1
    }
    Sleep 300000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay this may be a litte more then you need

but try it out and see if it works for you...

```
; Create the ListView with one column, Name:
Gui, Add, ListView, r20 w200 vMyListView, Name
; Create a object "online"
online := []
gosub, check ; Run the subpart one time
Settimer, check, 300000 ; and then this will run the cheak evry 300000 ms
return


check:
Gui, show ; Show the listveiw
GuiControl, -Redraw, MyListView ; Stop the listveiw from updateing
While A_Index < 5
{
    Url = website/LoggedIn&page=%A_Index%
    Source := URLToVar(URL)
    FileRead, Membs, MemberList.txt
    Loop, parse, Membs, `n
    {
        IfInString, Source, %A_LoopField%
        {
                SoundBeep
                Online[A_LoopField] := true
        }
        else if Online[A_LoopField]
            Online.Remove(A_LoopField)
    }
}
LV_Delete()
for key in online
{
    msgbox % Key
    LV_Add("", Key)
}
GuiControl, +Redraw, MyListView ; let the listveiw update
Return

GuiClose:  ; Indicate that the script should exit automatically when the window is closed.
ExitApp

URLToVar(URL) {
    ComObjError(0)
    WebRequest := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    WebRequest.Open("GET", URL)
    WebRequest.Send()
    Return WebRequest.ResponseText()
        , ComObjError(0)
    }
```

Hope it helps you out

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, blackholyman. I'll try this and let you know how it goes.